# Which communication system would you choose for the elevator?

Tags: serial, wireless, efficiency, cost

The communication system is used to connect the floor fixtures (e.g. elevator diplays, elevator call butons) to the control panel which is existed in the elevator machine room.

Please look at the following picture:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fg5vtm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Dn* represents the device connected at nth floor.

The first system uses serial communication (e.g. Canbus) to connect the devices to the control panel. The second system uses multihop wireless network to exchange information between the devices and the control panel.

**Which system should I use from both a technician and a business perspective? Why?**

**Assumptions:**

1. This is a 5 floor elevator.
2. Low data rate is sufficient.

I have asked many people who are working in this field; and I got answers (may be right or wrong) with no **facts** or **prove**. Links to the questions [(1)](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-comprehensive-answer-to-why-elevator-companies-would-prefer-using-wireless-technology-over-the-other-approaches), [(2)](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-elevator-companies-head-toward-wireless-elevators).

They claim that even though wireless system has higher initial cost, it is more cost effective.

There are many patents on the internet of famous companies that started to use wireless technology. It is mentioned in this [patent](http://www.google.ch/patents/US6446761) that the main reason for using wireless (and here where I got surprised) is to reduce the number of wires. I mean, how many wires are there in a serial communication system? (2 for Canbus). 
Why would you prefer using about 10 wireless modules (for 5 floor elevator) to avoid using a 2 wire cable.

**With that being said, would you shed light on my question?**

Comment: Why would anyone want to use a wireless system for this? A wired system is cheaper, easier, and probably more reliable.

Comment: @Felthry a wired system is more expensive, more complicated to make robust, and overall more likely to break, IMHO. Back your claims!

Comment: Wireless may be fine.  But a backup system for life-critical functions would be called for.  The backup is not necessarily some kind of wired communication.  It can be another wireless system.  For example: one wireless link from the cabin roof to the top of the shaft, and the second redundant wireless link to the bottom of the shaft.

Comment: Btw. I really love wireless elevator controls, their security is basically nonexistent and they are fun to play with. Not so much maybe for the people that want to use the elevators...

Comment: @PlasmaHH SDR shenanigans senses tingling! Unsecured lift controls: Where, how many :)?! ANALYZE ALL THE CYBERSPECTRUMZ!

Comment: @MarcusMüller: with the decomissioning of dvb-t I expect a lot of free rtl-sdr dongles to be available ;)

Comment: I literally ordered 23 from China, the first 19 arrived yesterday. Anyway, (professional) SDR devices haven't been on shortage for me even before that. I'm running short on wireless control systems to mess with!

Comment: @MarcusMüller In my experience, wired communications tend to be much more reliable, but harder to repair when they do break. Wireless systems are subject to much more significant interference, and since there are already wires going into the elevator for power, it wouldn't be hard to add a few for CAN signals. I'd say a few tens of meters of cat5 is cheaper than a wireless module per floor! If this was a retrofit, sure, it'd be more expensive, but the question didn't specify whether this was a new installation or retrofit, and I assumed the former.

Comment: there are some potential situations where the electrical separation of wireless could be advantageous, ex: floods, lightning, vandalism... if one button's malfunction, no matter how bad, can't affect others in the system, that's a clear reliability advantage.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Can you explain why you think a wired system (e.g. Canbus) is more expensive?

Comment: @Majid_L cables costs. Opening walls to lay cables costs.

Comment: @MarcusMüller In both approaches there should be traces for the power wires and other cables related to elevator safty system; and holes have to be opened in either case.

Comment: well, don't know about the elevator safety system, but the stationary buttons could very well be supplied with the normal power grid without laying dedicated cabling. Avoiding having yet another physical cabling system to look for was the idea!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Generally, or at least in my area, floor fixtures are supplied with 24V coming from the control panel. For that 24V cables have to existed in either case. Talking about openning holes, holes for the buttons could be avoided if energy harvesting buttons were used; because they don't need external supply. But still holes for the floor displays have to be opened to be supplied. Unfortunately, there are not energy harvesting displays yet.

Comment: @Majid_L but I thought you said you needed to choose fixtures, so I didn't assume there'd be already dedicated cabling that you'd wanted to keep. You could change that lack of energy harvesting displays by designing one :) or, actually, if you can live with a simple LCD, you could live of a single cell for quite some time. Not like the floor of an elevator changes all that often :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes I could find a work-around for the display. But according to the answers I have got till now, from both reliability and cost effectiveness perspectives, I am not able to see the light on the wireless system. Maybe wireless system is more attractive for multi-group elevators since there are more cabling, and it could be attractive for IoT applications as well.

Comment: @Majid_L indeed, I think that is a very fair assessment!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks for your help, it is really appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

First off:

Just because a company patented a technology doesn't mean it turned out to be a good idea. You have to patent things before you try them out in large scale or on the market. There's a lot of useless patents.

Anyway, the prime considerations for a system of this kind are:

- reliability
- cost

From the cost perspective, wireless would probably win these days – a transceiver is way cheaper than flexible cabling that can withstand years of operation.

From a reliability point of view, it's actually hard to compete with wired systems, seeing that elevators don't usually fail due to reliability problems in the controls. Overall, they fail very seldom.

However, there's no inherent advantage of cabling over wireless communications – both are subject to adverse effects. Where, in wireless systems, that is mainly interference (and noise), in wired systems, that would be cable wear and things like rodents, water leaks. Both would be suspectible to controller failure on each end.

So, if you'd actually plan to replace the established wired cabling scheme with wireless, you'd be the one in charge of making a very detailed estimate on the outage probability of your two systems.

Now, reliable wireless is not really a new topic, however, there's not millions of simple devices that have the same operational "run time" as cabled elevator systems. Still, there's modules and standards for robust narrowband communications. I don't see why these wouldn't work here, reliably, too. Spread spectrum, frequency hopping, highly repetitive transmitters would do the job with a "outage probability far below any level of significance".

It's definitely possible to interfere with a radio signal in a elevator tower, but it's also definitely possible to mess with cables.

In fact, I know there's companies that currently are developing wireless, low-latency, life-critical-quality local links. Their vision is that, through rigorous engineering, you can make a car where the break pedal wirelessly connects to the brake controllers, and it would be *at least* as reliable as a car where that is done electrically.

I don't really think for a nearly perfect channel such as the elevator tunnel, you should be using relay stations. Multihop doesn't improve reliability here, and distances are relatively short, and you get a line of sight.

Notice that in industrial productions, there's devices that run around on large floors and communicate with the controller via an antenna running along a slotted waveguide. So it's not really wireless communication, it's more like wired communication using RF to avoid physical contacts that can wear out, or cables that can flex too much and break.

---

in conclusion: this is an exercise in designing and evaluating reliable systems. It might not be the easiest thing to do for someone without a lot of product design and reliability experience (I certainly wouldn't think I could foresee all relevant risks and assess them; I do understand outage probabilities of wireless communications); so, if in doubt, stick with what is proven to work.

Comment: This can't be thought independent of the cabin lighting. Wireless communication only makes sense if the cabin lighting is done with rails or with a battery and charging terminals. If it is done with a cable, factoring out the communication from that cable saves you nothing.

Comment: Oh, and I'm pretty sure the costs for cabling explodes with the number of stories, because the cable has to carry its own weight and gets extremly expensive above a certain length.

Comment: Wireless controls need power, too. If the controls can't get power from the same cable they're communicating over, then they need a separate power source, which can only add complexity to the installation and maintenance of the system.

Comment: Indeed, but wireless short-term battery-aided comms would have advantages over separate comm cabling or power line communications in that they'd allow emergency calls even if there's a mechanical failure in the cabling conduit. Also, power could be supplied over a (very noisy) rail/brush system that would not lend itself to being double-used as a communication channel.

Comment: Oh, by the way, I just realized: we're all talking about the elevator cabin. Reading OP's question anew, I find him asking about the stationary buttons at each floor. IMHO, you'd use wiring for those, unless you have a reliable wireless  elevator communication method, in which case you might want to use the same for the stationary buttons.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes I am talking about just the floor fixtures. What about the claim from the elevator company owner (from the link I have shared) that "It is all about minimising field labour and therefore overall costs. My crews cost me between 2 and 3 dollars per minute, so every few minutes saved adds up pretty quickly.". In your opinion, does this make wireless cost-effective and attractive solution for highly productive companies?

Comment: @Majid_L I know you are making a point taken from the perspective of an installer and/or manufacturer. But what's good for them may not be the same thing as what is good for the end user, who doesn't just "get in and get out" of the situation but instead must live with the results for many years. Just want to make sure that all perspectives are given a voice.

Answer (score 4):

Note that we are talking about the floor fixtures here, not the lift car, so the costs of flexible cables with strength members required for the car itself is a non issue (And you still need to get power to the car anyway).

In a fixed installation, if you can practically run a wire, you really want to do so (And I speak as a broadcast engineer), especially in a situation where expected system life is measured in tens of years, and you do not know what the RF environment will be like even 10 years down the line*.

The issue for me is not reliability tomorrow (so much) as being able to maintain the damn thing in 20 years time, when the manufacturer of the RF modules is long out of business, the lift manufacturer has managed to loose the source code (Surprisingly common with old products), and the designer has retired. There is something to be said for systems that can be debugged with a multimeter and a wiring diagram.

Comment: You made a good point. Talking about reliability, wireless technology has been used in home automation and building managment systems for a long time; and it proved to be reliable.

Comment: I like that point of view :) upvote! Another aspect: privacy.

Comment: @Majid_L, I have seen elevator systems 50+ years old that still worked and were still maintainable, I also got expensively stuffed a few years ago when the UK government as part of preparing to sell of spectrum freed up by the move to digital TV forced the decommissioning a wide range of PMSE radio kit, annoying when the kit has a 5 year life, a disaster when it is built into your offices infrastructure. The cost of having the M&E guys install some conduit and pull some signal cable when building the shaft is NOTHING in the scale of a capital building project.